# Ruby - Inserting entries from CSV into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have an uploaded CSV file, which I parse like so:

```
CSV.foreach(@my_file.file.path) do |row|
    puts row[1]
end
```

The incoming CSV file has at least the following columns: "id", "name", "number", "phone", and "food".

I would like to do something like:

```
CSV.foreach(@my_file.file.path) do |row|
     //find the columns in "row" associated with "id", "name", "number"
     //even though I don't know definitively which column they will be in
     //for example, "name" may be the 2nd or 3rd or 4th column (etc)

     //insert into my_table values(id, name, number)

end
```

Note that the CSV file will always have column names as the first row, however from file to file, the ordering of those columns may differ.

Comment: You need the first line in the CSV file to name the columns, otherwise how can you process the records?

Comment: The first line does have column names, however the ordering of the columns may be different from file to file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code that will collect only the fields you care about into an array of hashes:

```
require 'csv'

fields_to_insert = %w{ id name food number phone }
rows_to_insert = []

CSV.foreach("stuff.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  row_to_insert = row.to_hash.select { |k, v| fields_to_insert.include?(k) }
  rows_to_insert << row_to_insert
end
```

Given the following contents of `stuff.csv`:

```
junk1,name,junk2,food,id,junk4,number,phone
foo,Jim,bar,pizza,123,baz,9,555-1212
baz,Fred,bar,sushi,55,foo,44,555-1213
```

`rows_to_insert` will contain:

```
[{"name"=>"Jim",
  "food"=>"pizza",
  "id"=>"123",
  "number"=>"9",
  "phone"=>"555-1212"},
 {"name"=>"Fred",
  "food"=>"sushi",
  "id"=>"55",
  "number"=>"44",
  "phone"=>"555-1213"}]
```

I'd take that and use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to insert them all at once:

```
SomeModel.import(rows_to_insert)
```

You could insert the records one at a time in the CSV loop, but that's inefficient, and because `id` is normally a protected attribute, you can't mass-assign it, so you'd have to do this to insert a single record:

```
some_model = SomeModel.new(row_to_insert.select { |k, v| k != "id" }
some_model.id = row_to_insert["id"]
some_model.save!
```

...or something similar.

Comment: Try `row.to_hash.values_at(*fields_to_insert)` instead of `row.to_hash.select { |k, v| fields_to_insert.include?(k) }`.

Answer (score 3):

If the first row are the header names you can use the `:headers => true` option to `parse` in order to use the first row as keys for the data.

```
text = File.read(@my_file.file.path)
csv = CSV.parse(text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  YourModel.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
end
```